# C# Deserialization of JSON for use in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, json, foreach, deserialization

I have json that is posted from a HTTP req. I am trying to deserialize it for use in a for each loop. Unfortunately, its format is kicking my ass as its a list of objects (i believe).

so far i have the following:

```
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await req.ReadAsStringAsync());

foreach (var p in jsonObj.hireSchedules)
    {
     ///do something
    }
```

My json is as below:

```
{
"hireSchedules": [
    {
        "plant": "7246054",
        "num" : "79",
        "hire": "1137277"
     },
    {
        "plant": "7246055",
        "num" : "80",
        "hire": "1137278"
     }
    ]
}
```

I have the following classes:

```
public class HireSchedule
{
    public string plant { get; set; }
    public string num { get; set; }
    public string hire { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<HireSchedule> hireSchedules { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `RootObject jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(await req.ReadAsStringAsync());` ?

Comment: i get the following error when utilizing that before my foreach loop: "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'RootObject' because 'RootObject' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Comment: When you get this error, how is your foreach statement ?

Comment: As above: foreach (var p in jsonObj.hireSchedule) { //stuff }

Comment: did the value of jsonObj parsed correctly before going through the foreach loop?

Comment: Yeah, that was an error in the copy/paste

Comment: To me this error message comes from something is trying to loop over something of type `RootObject`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have already defined the classes it's easy enough to deserialize it into them. Then you have a strongly typed class and the IDE should be able to help you out how to access the properties.

```cs
var json = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

foreach (var p in root.hireSchedules)
{
    ///do something
}
```

Comment: Using this method i receive the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. So, it is not deserializing right.

Comment: @jradata It seems like your JSON doesn't match your classes then, even though in the example you have provided above it does.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way is to use Newtonsoft.json nuget which is really very powerful, so

```
var files = JObject.Parse(YourJSON);
var recList = files.SelectTokens("$..hireSchedules").ToList();
foreach (JObject obj in recList.Children())
 {
   foreach (JProperty prop in obj.Children())
      {
        var key = prop.Name.ToString();
        var value = prop.Value.ToString();
         //Do your stuffs here
      }

  }
```